# How to catch an exception within loop/react of an actor?

Tags: scala, exception, actor

Is it possible to catch an exception raised within `behaviour`? Where to place the `try/catch`? I know that `react` uses exceptions to reuse the same thread for different actors and that´s why I don´t know where to put the `try/catch`. I want to catch certain exceptions by myself for logging.

```
import scala.actors._
def behaviour: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {
  case x => 
    println(x)
    throw new IllegalStateException
}

val a = new Actor {
  def act {
    loop {
      react {
        behaviour
      }
    }
  }
}
a.start
a ! "Bam"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eThe Actor has a exception handler function which can be overridden:

```
override def exceptionHandler = {
   case e: Exception =>
      println(e.getMessage())
}
```

Whenever a exception is raised in the actor that would normally cause it to terminate - the `exceptionHandler` partial function is applied to the exception.

---

**Edit**

With Exception filter:

```
  class ExceptionalActor extends Actor{

    def act() {
      loop {
        react {
          case "bad" => throw new NoSuchFieldException("Bad Message")
          case "impossible" => throw new Exception("Impossible Exception")
          case m => println("non-bad message " + m )
        }
      }
    }

    override def exceptionHandler = {
      case e: NoSuchFieldException => println("handled " + e.getMessage() )
    }
  }

  object Tester extends App {
    val eActr = new ExceptionalActor
    eActr start

    eActr ! "any message1"
    eActr ! "bad"
    eActr ! "any message2"
    eActr ! "impossible"
    eActr ! "any message3"
  }
```

produces:

```
   non-bad message any message1
   handled Bad Message
   non-bad message any message2
   org.scratch.act.ExceptionalActor@7f5663a2: caught java.lang.Exception: Impossible Exception
   :
```

And actor death.

ref: [Actors in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/actors_in_scala)

Comment: Cool! That´s exactly what I was looking for. I´m looking forward to see the book available on amazon. Thank you!